# OR Logic in if statement issue.

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic

I am having a problem with the logic in my if statement. I am trying to have it check to see if the strings character is equal to a, e, i, o, OR u. And then if so add the character to the phrase string. Else add "x" to the phrase string.

The if statement seems to disregard my OR logic and returns true regardless if it is a vowel of not.

```
function translate(string){
    var phrase = "";

    for(i=0; i<string.length; i++){
        if (string.charAt(i) === "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u"){
           phrase += string.charAt(i);

       }else{

            console.log("x");

         }
    }
    console.log(phrase);
}


translate("this is fun");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I think you should push "i" in an array every iteration of your loop

Answer (score 5):

```
if (string.charAt(i) === "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u"){
```

This is incorrect. If the first condition fails (the character is not `"a"`), it will always be *truthy* because it will evaluate `"e"`, which is *truthy* (JavaScript returns the last evaluated part of an expression in a condition).

You could use...

```
// Define them somewhere out of the loop.
var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

// Your new condition.
if (vowels.indexOf(string.charAt(i)) > -1) {
```

You could also rewrite the whole thing like...

```
var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
var phrase = string
              .split("")
              .filter(function(char) { return vowels.indexOf(char) > -1; })
              .join("");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FENYC/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to check each condition separately. For example:

```
if (string.charAt(i) === "a" || string.charAt(i) === "e" || ...);
```

To cut down on code bloat you can set a variable:

```
var char = string.charAt(i);

if (char === "a" || char === "e" || ...);
```

Or you can use this `indexOf` trick:

```
if (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].indexOf(string.charAt(i)) > -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In you code you are comparing `string.charAt(i)` with `"a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u"` which evaluates to `true`.

What you men to do is :

```
string.charAt(i) === "a" || string.charAt(i) === "e" 
|| string.charAt(i) === "i" || string.charAt(i) === "o" || string.charAt(i) === "u"
```

In english we say : `if my string is equal to 'a' or 'e' or 'i' ..` but in javascript (and most other languages) we say : `if my string is equal to 'a' or my string is equal to 'b' ..`

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this. The `.indexOf()` on strings is more widely available than the `.indexOf()` on Arrays.

```
if ("aeiou".indexOf(string.charAt(i)) > -1) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Alex's answer is pretty good, but rather than using *indexOf* and an array (noting that *Array.prototype.indexOf* is ES5 so not supported by older browsers), you can use an object instead:

```
var vowels = {a:'a', e:'e', i:'i', o:'o', u:'u'};

if (vowels.hasOwnProperty(string.charAt(i).toLowerCase())) {
    phrase += string.charAt(i);
} else {
    ...
}
```

The above is also not case sensitive, so A, E, I, O and U will also be added to the string. If you want it to be case sensitive, remove the `.toLowerCase()` part.

#### Edit

Alex got me thinking, again. To return an array of just the vowels in order:

```
function getVowels(s) {
  return s.match(/[aeiou]/g);
}
```

To return a string where all non-vowels (consonants) are replaced with an "x":

```
function replaceConsonants(s) {
  return s.replace(/[^aeiou]/g,'x');
}
```

To return a string of just the vowels:

```
function replaceConsonants(s) {
  return s.replace(/[^aeiou]/g,'');
}
```

or

```
function getVowels(s) {
  return s.match(/[aeiou]/g).join('');
}
```

etc.

Comment: Using split, filter, indexOf and join all in one go seems a tad excessive. ;-) A regular expression and *match* seems a candidate too.